# Symfony 4. Ошибка при загрузке файла

Tags: php, symfony4

У меня есть поле attachment для загрузки файла в форму. Это non-mapped поле. Соответственно в форме оно выглядит так:

```
->add('attachment', FileType::class, [
    'attr' => [
      'placeholder' => 'Выберите файл',
    ],
    'label' => 'Загрузите файл',
    'multiple' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'help' => 'Допустимые форматы: XLS, XLSX',
  ])
```

В контроллере я его обрабатываю такие образом:

```
$file = $form->get('attachment')->getData();
      $fileDir = $this->getParameter('data_dir');
      if (!is_dir($fileDir)) {
        mkdir($fileDir);
      }
      $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $file->move($fileDir, $fileName);
      $practice->setAttachment($file);
```

При загрузке файла он этот файл не видит, при отладке отображается, что attachment пустой.

Answer (score 0):

1. Как форму выводите?
2. Файл точно отправляется? Проверьте в инспекторе браузера во вкладке Network, что при запросе файл точно отправляется.

Comment: Форму вывожу в шаблоне twig. Файл именно не загружается в это поле attachment. Файл загружается туда, если у attachment mapped = true и если прописать в его Entity, но мне надо без этого

Comment: Почему без него? Судя по документации https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html#mapped
без него никак.

Comment: Я имею в виду, чтобы mapped = false было